# Web Data Streaming in Java EE

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, aspectj

we have a design like this :

[image]

our installed service upon tomcat has a method getDatabaseData(String request) (RMI Client) which receive data from database using (RMI Server implementation) existing on the core.

we want to do something that our installed service which is inside tomcat make a xml file and send it to client now :

we have thought about a solution that :

- first make the whole xml file on our tomcat using the getDatabaseData(String request) & then our user can get a reference using a link to it & start downloading the data.

but this solution is not informative for us because the size of this file is so big and if we want to do this our tomcat server storage will get full so fast & get down, so we're looking for a solution for real time streaming data to user instead of creating the whole file. I mean a way to send the data to user in a xml template when data is receiving from the CORE.

Do you have any idea ?

(by the way the web service upon tomcat has been written using Spring MVC & Spring Security)

Comment: How big is the file ? How many files do you expect to hold in a day ? Is the XML file unique for every call or can it be cached ?

Comment: the size might be more than 100MB for each request & the number of these files depends to the user requests which is unpredictable. the uniqueness of the xml file is depend to the userRequest (the  getDatabaseData() actually is something like this:  getDatabaseData(String request)) and if the String request be similar the data will be similar & for caching I'm not familiar with caching mechanism !

Comment: Out of curiosity, why the RMI-bridge?

Comment: 1) different servers in different locations (Core Servers & Tomcat Servers are in different locations) 2) the web & j2EE developers won't get involved to Core tasks & they won't see any implementation and core classes

Comment: @Deepak Bala if you mean client side caching we don't need it because if the whole data won't get receive, It's useless !

Comment: @Mehdi I think he means server side caching, since you'd have to create the XML files before sending them to the client, it would be better that you could cache the files on one of the servers - performancewise.

Comment: @Darwind no I don't want to do this because I don't want to create the file either in cache server or any other storage. I just want to push the data to user in real time when I'm receiving it from the server !

Comment: @Mehdi yes I understood that ;-) Anyways: I might be wrong, but if you're using a `Servlet` can't you just write the file to the `response`, while fetching the data from the database?

Comment: @Darwind no because this one is multipart streaming data not just a normal String !

Comment: @Mehdi You will need to walk a thin rope without persisting the XML to storage. The connection between User->Tomcat->Core->DB must be alive for the entire length of the download and must be stable. Network latency can cripple resources. A failed download will mean you need to start all over again. Are you sure you do not want to persist the XML ?

Comment: @DeepakBala I already know all the risks. yes with all of these risks I do not want to persist the xml & I need real time streaming without storing & caching any data because this scenario is kinda different and our expectation is different !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can give you a pice of code from my current project, where we return a file in struts action:

```
response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");
ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
out.write(file);
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Using ServletOutputStream  you can stream file directly to user from CORE through TOMCAT. In this case TOMCAT plays a proxy role.

Comment: I think, I have to check this again !

Answer (score 0):

using @Noofiz code, I wrote this code for testing this functionality & that worked for me!

we can read from a file and send it out on-time to user and let the user download the file !

1) I printed 'End!' to make sure that the file is sending to user on time when It's buffering and not finish buffering first & then send it to user !

2) the downloaded file & main file md5 checked and they were similar.

here is my servlet code :

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    InputStream is = new FileInputStream("/home/Mehdi/Desktop/log.log");
    response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
    ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
    int i;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[10 * 1024];

    while ((i = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        if (i != 10240) {
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                out.write(buffer[j]);
            }
        } else {
            out.write(buffer);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("End!");
}
```

Comment: don't worry, I'm not in hurry !

Comment: Writing a 100 MB file one byte at a time - `out.write(buffer[j]);`.  O.O The if condition is also unnecessary `if (i != 10240)` since there is no guarantee that buffer.length will be read even when you are not near EOF. Well... good luck.

Comment: @DeepakBala what I want to do in here is to buffer more byte (10*1024) to speed up streaming & the if in here means for example if the file size is (10*1024*X + Y) send the file X times using (10*1024) buffering & then send the rest byte to byte till the whole file get downloaded exactly as it is ! there are two important things here: 1) speed of all storage now a days is more than 10 kb 2) all of our files are more than 10 kb in our scenario. so did you understand what I mean now by this kind of coding ?
when I download the 110 MB using without byte array spend 1 min & using 2nd method 2 sec

Comment: I think I have to test my code for a file less than 10 kb also & see the result. because if for example file size be 2 kb, It's still match our condition [ i != 10240 ] & my code must have work, I'll check it out later & tell u the result ! if you guys have problem to understand the concept of my code just print i when you're streaming a big file & see what I mean by that !!!